# Building an android library in Jitpack: ERROR: No build artifacts found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jitpack

I've forked an Android library and merge some changes that I need
https://github.com/ceessay/kdgaugeView

In order to use the library in my Android project I've tried publishing it on Jitpack.

The problem is after pushing changes on Github, the builds on Jitpack seem to pass but there's this message

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 543ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
2020-07-13T12:27:13.425592193Z
Exit code: 0
ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

full log here: https://jitpack.io/com/github/ceessay/kdgaugeView/1.0.5/build.log

Adding the library in my project also failes with the following message:

> Could not find com.github.ceessay:kdgaugeView:1.0.4.

I've followed the guidelines on Jitpack documentation, Upgraded gradle on the library but i wont work.

I am new to publishing libraries for Android so I might be missing something. Any clue of what that is ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811778/12272687

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `maven-publish` gradle plugin. The documentation for `maven-publish` is https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin.

I'm sure it's also possible to use `com.github.dcendents.android-maven` which is already in that project, but it isn't as obvious to me.

You can also check out the excellent plugin https://vanniktech.github.io/gradle-maven-publish-plugin/.

Comment: The documentation helped, did not know it existed for android

Answer (score 0):

Spent half a day fighting the same problem. I forgot to define publication for my artifact in build.gradle.kts:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
      groupId = "com.github.username"
      artifactId = "library-name"
      version = "1.0.0"

      from(components["kotlin"])
    }
  }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Why from components kotlin, some say java others release. this is driving me crazy

Comment: you're not alone, i have spent two day on this issue and no solution works for me 